# CKEditor 5 function to toogle headlines on/off

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Is there a CKEditor 5 function to toggle paragraphs to headlines. So that if you activate it once, it makes the current paragraph to a headline, and if you click it again, it converts the headline back to a normal paragraph again.

For example, if I execute("numberedList") once, the current paragraph is converted to a list, and if I execute("numberedList") again, the list is converted back to a normal paragraph. Is there a similar command for headlines?

Answer (score 0):

There is a heading command, that works similarly. However, it does not toggle - you need to set to what element you want to rename. Call `editor.execute( 'heading', { value: elementName } );`. `elementName` can be a `paragraph` or any of the headings: `heading1`, `heading2`, etc.